# How to change multiple element's css during a timeout? (multiple progress bars)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, timeout

I'm developing multiple progress bars, the bars are stacked horizontal, like an Instagram story or a Facebook story, I'm trying to set the width of the first element with "bar" class by every 4 seconds, and later change the next element with "bar" class.

example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOY42.jpg

I tried the code below:

```js
count = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  while ($(".bar").css("width") != "100%") {
    count++
    for (i = 0; i < bar.length; i++) {
      bar[i].style.width = count + '%';
    }
  }
}, 4000);
```

Comment: change the timeout to `4000`, also that while will loop regardless of the timeout, you will loop everything immidiatly

Comment: Also you will never get 100% as a result of a .width call - use `if (count<100)`

Comment: i posted the wrong version, now its the real @mplungjan

Answer (score 0):

It took a while to figure out what you meant

One after the other

```js
var count = 0, len = $(".bar").length, w = 1;
var tId = setInterval(function() {
  $(".bar").eq(count).css({ width: w + '%' });
  w++;
  if (w>=100) { 
    w = 0; count++;
    if (count>=len) clearInterval(tId); // stop
  }
}, 200);
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
  width: 0;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 0;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="bar red">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="bar yellow">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="bar green">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

---

One by one

```js
var count = 0, len = $(".bar").length, w = 1;
var tId = setInterval(function() {
  $(".bar").eq(count).css({ width: w + '%' });
  count++;
  if (count >= len) { 
    count = 0; w++; 
    if (w>=100) clearInterval(tId); // stop
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
  width: 0;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 0;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="bar red">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="bar yellow">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="bar green">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's working brother, but its change the width off all bars in the same time, i want, change the first element, later change the second one, etc..

Comment: Thanks brother, you are awesome, its what a needeed, have a good day